Как в паттерне разрешить ввод знака №?
у меня есть такой паттерн, который разрешает только русские буквы и некоторые символы:
value: /^[а-яёА-ЯЁ\s\-\,\.\!\?\\:\;\"\(\)\d]+$/

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы он разрешал вводить и знак номера №?
Я добавляла и так, и с помощью кодировки, ничего не помогает (
/^[а-яёА-ЯЁ\s\-\,\.\!\?\\:\;\"\(\)\d\№]+$/


обратный слэш не нужен в данном случае.

Вы имеете в виду после d?

вы добавили символ номера, а перед ним зачем-то вставили обратный слэш. не знаю, получите ли вы в итоге нужное вам поведение, но вот обратный слэш в данном случае точно не нужен.

Спасибо, убрала, но все равно не работает, как нужно

Экранирование в наборах нужно далеко не всем символам:
/^[а-яёА-ЯЁ\d\s.,:;!?\\"()№-]+$/

В данном выражении экранированы только символьные классы \d и \s, а также обратный слэш \\.

Спасибо, но почему-то именно знак № не позволяет написать

@Виктория, добавьте пример входных данных.

Все, разобралась, теперь работает, спасибо большое)
